# Are Jews allowed to listen to music that is performed by non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, gentiles, music

I am *machmir* on only listening to music that was performed by a Jew, but i don't really understand it. Does anyone know what is the source for this? Does Matisyahu perform with only Jews?

Comment: I have been to many Chasunos where some of the band members were non Jews

Comment: If you don't understand it, why do you do it? I'm not being facetious, just trying to understand your thought process.

Comment: @dave because my rav said so

Comment: From your question it sounded like you decided to do this yourself (hence my confusion). Why don't you ask the Rav who told you this in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Igros Moshe YD 2:111 where he raises issue of church influence which relate to the players' intentions, the words, and the instruments. Jews presumably would not have suspicious (regarding idol worship) intentions.

Answer (score 9):

[Here's](http://learningteshuvot.blogspot.com/2011/01/listening-to-gentile-music-igrot-moshe.html) a summary of Igrot Moshe Yoreh Deah 2:56, which says that the bottom line is that "it is forbidden to listen to non-Jewish religious music ... However, if the song is written and/or song by a non-Jew but has no religious purpose, then there is technically no prohibition."

Comment: So, I can listen to Bach Cantatas or Handel's Messiah? Or Norman Greenbaum's "Spirit in the Sky", written by a Jew claiming he'll have a place with Jesus?

Comment: @DanF I would think that Handel's Messiah and Greenbaum's "Spirit in the Sky" have religious purposes.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I would most definitely agree regarding Messiah, esp. since it tends to be sung close to Christmas season. "Spirit in the sky" was not composed to be a religious song. I think it was just meant to be a catchy tune for rock radio listeners, which it was. I don't think they are singing this song in any church.

Answer (score 3):

I heard a prominent Rabbi say that it was mutar as long as the lyrics and clean and the beat will not make one do inappropriate things.  (See Rambam's comment on Avots 1:16)

Comment: How does reading Rambam's comment there make anything more clear?

Answer (score 2):

In a [Q&A session](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/752586/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Press_Conference-_What_is_Modern_Orthodoxy,_non-Jewish_music,_Yom_Ha%27atzmaut,_and_many_more_topics) by R' Hershel Schachter I recently heard, he explains (I forget based on who) that artists put some of their essence into the art they make, so when you consume art, you internalize a little bit of the artist's soul. So, he advocates against listening to music composed by non-Jews.

Comment: I think the question was about music being *performed* by non-Jews. That does not automatically follow from the principle you mentioned.

Comment: Agreed, although I suspect that he'd say that the rule is the same. I recommend that you listen to the recording to get his nuances and see if he quoted a source.

Comment: @isaac no its not the same. there's a difference between me performing beethoven on the piano and some ali ahmad or james jones doing beethoven

Comment: @avrohom Your first sentence seems to be disagreeing with me, while your second sentence seems to be agreeing with me. In any case, the reality is that when you hear music, the emotions of both the composer and the performer are expressed therein, in different ways and to different degrees. How that should affect practice is either a Halachic question for your Rabbi, R' Schachter, and whatever sources they cite or a personal matter.